# Is there any way to get the table hierarchy from a connection string in c#?

Tags: c#, sqlclient

I have a current requirement to determine the table hierarchy from a sql statement within c#.  For example, consider the following sql statement:

```
Select Table1.*, Table2.* from Table1 
left join table2 on Table1.parentCol = Table2.childCol
```

That might return 7 columns, 3 for Table1 and 4 for table2.  I need to know the column names, and ideally (though not mandatory) their types.

I have no control over what SQL Statement will be used, as this is a user entered field.  In C# it's a very basic task to open a connection and create an SqlCommand using that statement.  I have freedom to run the SQL into a SqlDataReader, or any other System.Data.SqlClient class if necessary, however I cannot find any combination that will return the columns, rather than the actual column values.

Is anyone able to help?

Many thanks and best regards

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do what you are asking (easily).

More to the point, do not let users enter arbitrary TSQL (You will regret it at some point...).

Instead, create a 'Search' form that allows entering various params and use a parameterised query onto a view that joins all the tables/columns required.

Comment: @Mitch - I think its too hard a statement - how about http://data.stackexchange.com/. There might be valid reasons to let user enter arbitrary TSQL. Though I agree, one should be very careful when developing apps like this.

Comment: It is practically never a good design to let users enter arbitrary TSQL. That's what SSMS is for!

Comment: It's not as simple as that unfortunately, since the sql queries may contain complicated joins, both inner and outer, and it would be very difficult to present a search form to accommodate that.  Not only that, but the datadase is dynamic.

Comment: However, at the moment I am looking at something along the lines of a DataTable, which can be found using DataTable.GetSchemaTable().  Hopefully it may be along the lines of what I need

Comment: @Adam: I've done it this way, many times. It is not that difficult.

Comment: @Mitch - In general I agree, 99 out of 100 times you can avoid it, but what about usage similar to data.stackexchange.com? One car argue an API would be much better, but that may not be as convenient or flexible for end user.

Comment: I've now found the answer here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/310107.  I can't answer my own question though because I'm a new user.  Thanks all

Answer (score 0):

There's no direct way. You'll need to parse names of all the tables from the sql query.

Once you have done that you'll need to write few queries on [Information_Schema](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186778.aspx) to get raw data for what you are looking for.

If you are on SQL Server, you may want to use [Catalog View](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189783.aspx)

ex-

```
Select * from sys.tables where [Name] = 'MyTable'
```